# How to integrate this matrix function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I'm wondering how can I integrate this matrix differential equation:

$$
\dot{L_{ij}}(t) = K_{im}L_{mj}(t) \,\, .
$$

My gess is to perform a separation of variable and then integrate both sides, like this,

$$
\int \frac{dL_{ij}(t)}{L_{mj}(t)} = \int K_{im} dt \,\, .
$$

Is that method right? If yes, How could I perform the integration in the left hand of the equation above? I'm finding difficult in treating with the indices ...

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. I assume that there is an understood *summation* over $m$?

Comment: Yes, and that $K$ is a constant matrix..

Comment: Then $L(t)=e^{Kt}L(0)$ in analogy to the scalar case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a matrix ODE $\dot{L}=KL$ is just a system of separate ODEs $\dot{\mathbf{x}}_i = K \mathbf{x}_i$,
one for each $i$, where $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the $i$th column of $L$.

And how to solve an equation of the form
$\dot{\mathbf{x}} = K \mathbf{x}$ with constant $K$
is covered in almost every ODE textbook (or [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation)).

Answer (score 1):

The repeated index $m$ just [means a summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) over all possible values that index can take

$$
K_{im}L_{mj} = K_{i1}L_{ij} + K_{i2}L_{2j} + \cdots 
$$

So you *cannot* divide by $K_{lm}$ as you suggest. This is just a coupled system of differential equations. Depending on the nature of $K$ (constant, $t$-dependent, $\dots$) there are ways of solving the system.